# Get text in neted html tags with regex in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I have a text with html tags:

```
<p><b>Name and LastName</b><br />
Work Title<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
```

I want to have text in this format:

```
Name and LastName - Work Title
```

This is my code in Python but doesn't works:

```
text = '<p><b>Name and LastName</b><br />
    Work Title<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
    </p>'
my_text = re.sub(r'</b><br />', ' - ', text)
```

Comment: Do not try to [parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use something like BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a specialized tool for the job - an *HTML Parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """<p><b>Name and LastName</b><br />
    ...: Work Title<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
    ...: </p>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: soup.p.get_text(separator=" - ", strip=True)
Out[4]: u'Name and LastName - Work Title'
```

Note the use of `separator` argument - it allows to provide a custom separator between the child nodes while getting the text of the parent - pretty neat feature that fits your use case nicely.

Comment: And if I have few items, this code return only first... @alecxe